# Fitting distribution on a histogram

Tags: statistics

I am stuck with the following problem from research. I have a histogram of a data, and I need to fit a distribution to the histogram. Is there a way to do this in say R or matlab? Can anybody suggest some algorithms.

PS: I cannot run the distribution fit on the data. I need to run on the histogram.

Comment: plot(density(x)) will give you a kernel density estimate....is that what you mean? Are you trying to fit a specific parametric family or does it have to be nonparametric?

Comment: But density can only be applied to data not the histogram

Comment: I think @Bey is referring to `ksdensity` in Matlab. Why do you need a histogram? It's an unnecessary intermediate step and fitting to it will result in a less accurate fit.

Comment: anup was was referring to the R function. But I agree with @horcher...if you have the data, why use the histogram?

Comment: You can probably discern heights of bars accurately enough to be able to find the sample mean and SD. Then if you have some candidate families of distributions you can start by estimating distribution parameters, and then do goodness of fit tests to see which members of which family(ies) are good fits. It is possible you may find several possible fits. I know of no statistical method that will $suggest$ distribution families.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kernel density estimate.

plot(density(x,bw = "ucv")), main = "kernel density estimate", col = "red", lwd = 3)

and bw = "ucv" means to set the unbiased cross validation bandwidth

Comment: I believe this method relies on having the data in the vector $x$.